# OpenCms tags in OpenCms tags

Tags: opencms

I know this may be a silly question but I ma trying to understand the jsp templates in opencms.

Even though we have htm tags in jsp. what is the actual use of cms tags such as :

```
 <cms:template element="body">
<cms:include element="body" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As described in this wiki [page](http://www.opencms-wiki.org/wiki/Including_your_template_elements_within_your_JSPs) you can define your template parts in a jsp file through cms tag cms:template and then include them in your jsp page through cms tag cms:include

Answer (score 0):

**The cms:template tag**

With the  tag, you can add control structures to the template which allows it to deal with multiple page elements.

**The cms:include tag**

This tag is used to include files from the OpenCms VFS dynamically at runtime. The included file is treated like a request with optional additional request parameters.
There are different options to determine the name of the included file by using one of the following attributes:
 - page
 - property 
 - attribute

If none of these attributes has been set, the body of the  tag is evaluated and the result is used as filename.

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="cms" uri="http://www.opencms.org/taglib/cms" %>

<cms:template element="head">

<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title><cms:property name="title" escapeHtml="true" /></title>

<meta HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="text/html; CHARSET=<cms:property name="content-encoding" default="ISO-8859-1" />">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<cms:link>../resources/mystyle.css</cms:link>">

<cms:editable />

</head>
<body>

<h2>My first template head</h2>

<!-- Main page body starts here -->
</cms:template>

<cms:template element="body">

<h2>This is the first page element:</h2>

<cms:include element="body" editable="true"/>

<cms:template ifexists="body2">
<h2>This is the second page element:</h2>
<cms:include element="body2" editable= "true"/>
</cms:template>


</cms:template>

<cms:template element="foot">
<!-- Main page body ends here -->

<h2>My first template foot</h2>

</body>
</html>
</cms:template>
```